# proving that two principal ideals are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $k$ is a field. Consider the ring $k[x,y]$ consisting of polynomials in the variables $x$ and $y$ with coefficients in $k$. Prove that in the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(x{y^2})$, the principal ideals $(x)$, and $x+xy$ are equal. One inculsion is clear-since $x+xy=x(1+y)\in{(x)}$, $(x+xy)\subset(x)$. I am having a hard time proving the reverse inclusion!

Answer (score 2):

Let $I=(xy^2)$.

Working mod $I$, we get
$$(x+xy)(1-y)=x(1+y)(1-y)=x(1-y^2)=x-xy^2=x$$
so $x\in (x+xy)$.

Here's still another way . . .

Let $J=(x+xy)$.$\;$Then working mod $I$, we get
\begin{align*}
&x+xy\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&y(x+xy)\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&xy+xy^2\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&xy\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x+xy)-xy\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x\in J\\[4pt]
\end{align*}